# SignalR selfhost server does not working

Tags: c#, service, signalr, self-hosting

We've developed SignalR selfhost server in "**c#.net as window services**" and accessed by mobile application as client. We've developed with help of this link http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host.

This window services is running fine and after couple of days, mobile server could not response to the mobile client. We didn't know the reason why server is not working after couple of days.But window service is running successfully only didn't response to mobile client.

Also we tried restart service for every 6 hours but still we have no solution. Our code on server side is
**Startup class**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration() { EnableJSONP = true });
    }
}
```

**Service class**

```
public partial class MobileService : ServiceBase
{
    //SignalR
    private IDisposable signalR { get; set; }
    public string App_ServerURL = null;   
    public MobileHub obj_HubCMobileServer = new MobileHub();     
    public MobileService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
                    App_ServerURL = "http://192.168.1.4:8888";
                    obj_HubCMobileServer.Init();
                    Task.Run(() => StartServer());                   
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MobileService.Instance.server_Log(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
           // server_Log("SignalR server init  " + App_ServerURL);
            signalR = WebApp.Start(App_ServerURL);                
            server_journal("SignalR server started at  " + App_ServerURL);
            GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50);                               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            server_Log(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            return;
        }

    }
```

**HUB class**

```
public class MobileHub : Hub
{
    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MobileHub>();

    static readonly object thisLock = new object();
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public void Init()
    {
        try
        {                
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;                 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MobileService.Instance.server_Log(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }  
    .....
    .....
    .....
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
                  return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {           
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {

        return (base.OnReconnected());
    }
```

}

Anyone could you give solution or is there anyway restart mobile SignalR selfhost server for every 12 hours?

Comment: Your questions lacks the details that will provide an answer from this community. Strip down the code of your solution(s) to the bare minimum that reproduces the problem (The server not responding after some time?) and post that code in your question. did you do any debugging other than restarting the service? Did you try [fiddler](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Using-fiddler-with-signalr)?

Comment: Signlar creates Hub per each client request.
So you should not create any `Timer` inside the hub.

Try to remove timer and check